# run a Java program in specific time

Tags: java, time, runtime, timer-jobs

i need help to run my Java program on the server at a specific time like 2 pm (to index the new files).

Someone told me that Java has some thing called jobs but I don't know how to work with that. I tried this:

```
 boolean cond=true;
 while(cond){
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     int heur = new Date().getHours();
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     int minute= new Date().getMinutes();
     if(heur==16 && minute==02){
         indexer.close();
         end = new Date().getTime();
         File f;
         cond=false;
     }
```

But with this the program is still running.

How could I run my program at a specified time?

Comment: plz format your code properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a API called [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), It's where your program can schedule "Jobs" and it will run it at that time.

Until I can give an example, try [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/).

Edit: 
First you have to create a class that implements org.quartz.Job.  When you implement that you will have to implement the method `execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecution)`,  which is the method that will run when the "trigger" is fired.

To set up the Schedule:

```
SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
// Retrieve a scheduler from schedule factory
Scheduler scheduler = null;
try {
    scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
}
catch (SchedulerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Set up detail about the job 
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("jobDetail", "jobDetailGroup", ImplementedJob.class);
SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("Trigger Name","defaultGroup", DATE);

// schedule a job with JobDetail and Trigger
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrigger);
// start the scheduler
scheduler.start();
```

Comment: could you give an exemple how to use !!  i download it but should i put my code between the start() and shutdown() calls. How can i give it the time

Comment: why use quartz when the standard library has what you need?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `Thread.sleep()` call in the loop, so it will "spin" at 100% CPU (not good), but it's a poor design anyway. A big improvement would be to simply calculate the number of milliseconds between "now" and when you want it to run, then call Thread.sleep(n).

However, a better solution is to use what the JDK already provides.

Have a look at this code which uses classes from the JDK *concurrent* library.
This is a very simple example that would work:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            // do something;
        }
    };

    // Run it in 8 hours - you would have to calculate how long to wait from "now"
    service.schedule(runnable, 8, TimeUnit.HOURS); // You can 
}
```