# How do you write a silently self-starting, long-running, time-triggered Java desktop application without registering it as a Windows service?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, background-service, system-tray

I'm trying to build a report-building tool (which has a UI written in JavaFX) that has the following features:

1. When the system (re-)boots, it should auto-start in the background (without showing the UI)
2. **It should have an icon in the system tray**
3. *The UI should only show when the user clicks on the system tray icon*
4. *A report should be generated either once a day/week/month, at a specific time, automatically*
5. **It should "snooze/sleep" in the interim period and use minimal resources while it awaits the next trigger time**
6. *It should show a toast pop-up / Windows notification / whatever when a new report has been generated*

(The bold ones are the real problems, the italics are maybe solvable--given some resources I found--and the un-formatted one I have a work-around for, namely to place it on in the Startup folder in the AppData folder of the users' machine.)

But the clincher is the following: due to my company's policies, **I'm NOT allowed to build register it as a Windows service**. Also, converting it into a web service, placing it on a server, and using Control-M (or a cron expression) are also off the table. (That's a long story for another day.) I'm not sure how to implement it and I've been stuck on this for a bit.

I've taken a look at [Quartz](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/), [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6201197), and some other resources on how to run the Java app in the background, but most resources tell me to add it as a Windows service and I keep hitting a brick wall. Also, I don't know how much of an effect the application would have on the users' machines if I ran the application in the background with the solutions mentioned in the other StackOverflow answer. I need to have a minimal processing footprint in the interim period.

I'm also unsure of how to package the application as an EXE. For now, I'm going to turn it into an executable JAR. (Any help on this would also be welcome.)

I'm open to any suggestions and ideas and even other resources to look at for further reading. Anything to help me out here is welcome.

Comment: As for the Java app sleeping until a certain moment, and consuming virtually no CPU during that sleep, learn about the Executors framework. Specifically the `ScheduledExecutorService` class and the `Executors` utility class. Use those to make a background thread to run your report after a captain amount of time elapses.  Start with Oracle’s tutorial. Then search Stack Overflow to learn more. This has been covered many times already. As for the MS Windows integration, I can’t help there. This may be a good Question for that part.

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for that. I'll look into the framework and try to get it working in my app.

Comment: I would guess the down-vote is the same as the close votes: Needs more focus. You asking too many things at once. I suggest you rewrite to focus on the Windows integration. The Executors framework handles the part you asked about deferred execution, and you’ll find solutions in other Questions, so remove that aspect. And packaging as .exe is another question, likely asked already, so remove that. Always **search Stack Overflow thoroughly** before posting.